# Can I remove mold from moss with anti fungal?

Tags: fungus, mold, moss

I had some java moss growing in a closed box, doing well. But I noticed white stringy growth that I thought was fungus since it doesn't get any direct sun.

I sprinkled some anti fungal made of Carbendazim 12% + Mancozeb 63% in the box and in 2 days, moss became yellow from bright green and is getting worse.

So is quantity of the anti fungal an issue or does fungicide kill moss in any amount?

[image]

Comment: Photos would help, please

Comment: added image to Q